# Can I run my C# .exe on a rented / cloud computer?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, cloud

I have built a working C# application, a multi-threaded application that crunches numbers for research.

I can only go so far with my own PC, so I'm wondering if there exists a service where I can rent a high powered computer that can run my C# code. Something with a lot of processor cores,  so I could run... say, 64 threads concurrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Azure can do that. Just install a VM and create an as big machine as you need.

Troy Hunt wrote a good [blog post](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/11/using-high-spec-azure-sql-server-for.html) about how he used a cloud SQL Server for that kind of job.

Comment: I gave it a go... wow, was very fast to get a virtual machine up and running with their free trial. Incredible technology, wow. With the Remote Desktop connection I simply dragged and dropped my .exe onto the desktop and was running within 30 seconds. Crazy.

But, I can only get an 8 core machine setup which is the same as my own PC... and my .exe ran slower in Azure.

Maybe I can run multiple virtual machines at the same time, unless I'm missing something that's the only way to get some decent parallel processing happening.

Answer (score 1):

In [windows Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn197896.aspx) you can create your service model, can specify the size to which to deploy an instance of your role, depending on its resource requirements.

[Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) also provides a number of options to choose an instance as per your requirement.